# How to check category of of custom post type or not

Tags: categories, theme-development, themes

I have a `category.php` file in my theme. Now the problem is in wordpress category can be of many things.

Like there is a default blog post category. Then there are category for custom post types, like portfolio, logo etc.

Now for all of these categories the same `category.php` file gets fired.

But in my `category.php` I'm trying to show something only if it is the category of main blog post type. If it is the category of any other custom post types, then that thing will now show up.

Is there is way to check if the category is of default blog post type or some custom post types?

So that I can do something like this:

```
if( this is the category of the main blog post type ) {
// then show what I want
} else {
// don't
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So basically you want to use the `category.php` for a particular `post_type`'s category, right ? I think you can make sure the thing like below-

```
if( 'your-main-blog-post-type' == get_post_type() ) {
    // then show what I want
} else {
    // don't
}
```

Use above logic in your `category.php` and I hope you'll get the solution you're looking for.